# How can I display the current section name in a top dropdown nav using scrollspy?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, scrollspy

I want to display the section's name on the dropdown tab using bootstrap scrollspy. When I scroll now, I only see `section` (which I would exclude) and I would like to see the current section in the dropdown bar as in when its not opened. So when I touch `section 2` while scrolling I would like to see  `section 2` in the dropdown bar on top. At first, of course, I would like the bar to display `section 1`.

This is my code: https://codepen.io/alyssaalex/pen/rNNGrLy

I would appreciate it if someone could provide some help in this regard. Thanks!

Comment: If you open the dropdown, you can see the section 1 & section 2 displays selected respectively on the scroll. You can toggle as opened the dropdown menu when the scroll reaches the section 1 or section2.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I have updated my question. I want the current section to be shown on the dropdown bar(when not expanded) and of course the existing functionality of the dropdown bar when expanded remains.

Comment: I have created a demo for you. Please try it, and let me know if any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger an event on section change. And then get the section name and put on the dropdown title.

add this code in your JS

```
$(".navbar").on("activate.bs.scrollspy", function(){
  $("#section_ddl").html('');
  var sections = new Array("Section 1", "Section 2");
  var x = $(".nav li.active > a").text();
  if(sections.indexOf(x) != -1){
    $("#section_ddl").html(x + '<span class="caret"></span>');
  }
  else {
    $("#section_ddl").html('Section <span class="caret"></span>');
  }
});
```

If you add/remove sections, you only need to put section names in the `sections` array.

Note: `section_ddl` is the id of the dropdown.

[You can see the working example here](https://codepen.io/aalokmali/pen/abbVppy)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I modified it a bit to fit my needs and that worked!